# Why would an amphibious Storm Giant need to cast Water Breathing?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

In the MM, on page 156, a Storm Giant is described as

> Amphibious. The giant can breathe air and water

Yet it has the innate spellcasting ability to cast *water breathing* 3 times a day.

Why would it need to cast *water breathing* if it can already breathe water as a natural ability?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The water breathing spell can be used on other creatures (up to ten per casting to be exact). Creatures like, adventurers or other allies it has.